# Publish rasa project on docker hub

Tags: chatbot, rasa

I want to upload my rasa project on docker hub. I dont know how to create image?
Can anyone guide me? I am following this tutorial but it seem less understandable for me
https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/1.7.4/user-guide/how-to-deploy/
Getting this error

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkemh.png]

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have created a Rasa application, defined stories and intents, and trained the NLU model. It runs locally and now you need to dockerize it.

You can build your Rasa application creating a Dockerfile in the project root.

```
# start from base Rasa image
FROM rasa/rasa:1.10.1
# add project files
COPY . /app
```

In order to build the image

```
docker build -t my_rasa_app .
```

The result is a Docker image with you application built on top of Rasa. You can now run it, push it to GitHub or deploy to Docker Containers (ie Heroku)

Comment: Do you know how can i create dockerfile in windows?

Comment: Whats need to be added in dockerfile? like to install rasa or anything else? @Beppe C

Comment: The Dockerfile is a txt file (see example in my answer), you dont need to install Rasa to build an image, just start from the Rasa base image.